# Mvvm Light ListBox MouseButtonLeftDown and EventToCommand - how to pass clicked item

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I've data bound a ListBox in my MVVM Light Windows Phone 7 app, and want to invoke a command in my view model when the user clicks on an item in my ListBox.

I'm doing this using the EventToCommand behaviour and everything is good, except that I can't pass the data item associated with the list element that was clicked, if I use the MouseLeftButtonDown event ...

If I use the SelectionChanged event, then I can bind the behaviour's CommandParameter to the ListBox's SelectedItem, but I really want to use the MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Any ideas?  I'd prefer not to pollute my View Model by setting the "PassEventArgsToCommand" option, and in any event I'm not sure I can get the selected data item from the MouseButtonEventArgs.

Right now I'm heading towards setting up an event handler in the code-behind, and invoking the ViewModel from there, using the "sender" to get at the data item.

Thanks,

```
Damian
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the question doesn't actually make sense - the MouseLeftButtonDown event being fired on the ListBox is not associated with a particular item in the ListBox.

Instead, I'm looking to hook up to this event on the ItemTemplate I've associated with the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse Liberty gives a good example here: [Passing Parameters...](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/09/passing-parameters-with-behaviors-in-mvvm-light-for-windows-phone/)

But if you're using Windows Phone 7.5 you have to change one thing, which is you cannot use the Galasoft EventToCommand syntax anymore, as shown here in this example:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
    <!--<GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand x:Name="SelectionCommand" Command="{Binding SwitchProfileCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lboxProfiles}"/>-->

    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SwitchProfileCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lboxProfiles}" />

</i:EventTrigger>
```

Also, for Windows Phone 7.5, check out http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/ListBox-ContextMenu-with-MVVM-in-Windows-Phone for using a command with a context menu linked to each item.